# Having trouble with connected component labeling algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, components

So I've been trying to write a connected-component labeling algorithm but it's not giving me the desired result. Right now I have an image with 3 roses (that are not overlapping) and I want to label each rose with its own grey value. Before I apply the labeling algorithm I use a threshold to get rid of the background and only keep the roses. The roses get the gray value 1 (which is completely white) and the background gets gray value 0 (which is black). Here's an image of what this looks like:
[image]

After doing this I apply the labeling algorithm. It should give the roses three different gray values according to the label they've been given. But instead the algorithm creates this weird sort of gradient pattern over the first two roses whereas the last one seems to be a single gray value. Here's an image:
[image]

The algorithm might look complicated but it's actually really simple. I recurse on the columns first and then the rows and for each non-background pixel I check if any of its neighbors are already labeled (meaning their objectArray value is not zero). If so I add them to a list of neighbors. I then proceed to check if this list is not empty, if so I uniquely label the current pixel by incrementing the objects value and assigning its value to the current pixel's label value and I also set the current pixel's parent value to this unique label. If it's not empty, I determine the smallest label value in the neighbor list, set all the neighbors' parent values to this label value and I set the current pixel's label and parent values to this label value. I repeat this for every pixel until the whole image has been labeled.

Once this is done I recurse on the pixel values again, this time to set each pixel's label value to its parent value. I then proceed to assign the pixel a new gray value depending on its label value.

I don't understand why the algorithm isn't labeling the roses properly. Can anybody help me out? Here's the algorithm:

```
public void label()
{
    int objects = 1;
    int[,] objectArray = new int[colors.GetLength(1), colors.GetLength(0)];
    DisjointSets disjointSet = new DisjointSets();
    int[,] parents = new int[colors.GetLength(1), colors.GetLength(0)];
    List<List<int>> eqSet = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.GetLength(1); i++) for (int j = 0; j < colors.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        if (this[i, j].Gray == 1)
        {
            List<Label> neighbors = new List<Label>();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                if (this[i - 1, j].Gray == 1)
                {
                    if (objectArray[i - 1, j] != 0)
                    {
                        neighbors.Add(new Label(i - 1, j, 0));
                    }
                }
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    if (this[i - 1, j - 1].Gray == 1)
                    {
                        if (objectArray[i - 1, j - 1] != 0)
                        {
                            neighbors.Add(new Label(i - 1, j - 1, 0));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (j < colors.GetLength(0))
                {
                    if (this[i - 1, j + 1].Gray == 1)
                    {
                        if (objectArray[i - 1, j] != 0)
                        {
                            neighbors.Add(new Label(i - 1, j, 0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (j > 0)
            {
                if (this[i, j - 1].Gray == 1)
                {
                    if (objectArray[i, j - 1] != 0)
                    {
                        neighbors.Add(new Label(i, j - 1, 0));
                    }
                }
                if (i < colors.GetLength(1))
                {
                    if (this[i + 1, j - 1].Gray == 1)
                    {
                        if (objectArray[i + 1, j - 1] != 0)
                        {
                            neighbors.Add(new Label(i + 1, j - 1, 0));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i < colors.GetLength(1))
            {
                if (this[i + 1, j].Gray == 1)
                {
                    if (objectArray[i + 1, j] != 0)
                    {
                        neighbors.Add(new Label(i + 1, j, 0));
                    }
                }
                if (this[i + 1, j + 1].Gray == 1)
                {
                    if (objectArray[i + 1, j + 1] != 0)
                    {
                        neighbors.Add(new Label(i + 1, j + 1, 0));
                    }
                }
            }
            if (j < colors.GetLength(0))
            {
                if (this[i, j + 1].Gray == 1)
                {
                    if (objectArray[i, j + 1] != 0)
                    {
                        neighbors.Add(new Label(i, j + 1, 0));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (neighbors.Count == 0)
            {
                objects++;
                objectArray[i, j] = objects;
                parents[i, j] = objects;
            }
            if (neighbors.Count > 0)
            {
                int smallestLabel = 10000;
                foreach (Label x in neighbors)
                    if (objectArray[x.X, x.Y] < smallestLabel)
                        smallestLabel = objectArray[x.X, x.Y];

                foreach (Label x in neighbors)
                    parents[x.X, x.Y] = smallestLabel;

                objectArray[i, j] = smallestLabel;
                parents[i, j] = smallestLabel;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.GetLength(1); i++) for (int j = 0; j < colors.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        if (this[i, j].Gray == 1)
        {
            if (objectArray[i, j] != 0)
            {
                objectArray[i, j] = parents[i, j];
                ColorWrap c = this[i, j];
                c.X = (float)objectArray[i, j] / objects;
                c.Y = (float)objectArray[i, j] / objects;
                c.Z = (float)objectArray[i, j] / objects;
                this[i, j] = c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply an int value for each pixel that makes up an object that I use to give those objects a particular gray value. The algorithm should check the image for connected pixels and give each "object" it finds (a "group" of connected pixels, which should be each of the roses) a label value (for example, pixels that make up the top left rose will get label value 1, the bottom left rose pixels will each get label value 2 and the pixels making up the right rose will each get label value 3). I use these label values to give these pixels a new gray value (c.X = (float)objectArray[i, j] / objects; etc)

Comment: @user1683526 is this a binary image or gray scale ?

Comment: It's a colored image that is converted to gray scale before I do the rest of the operations on it. I probably should've been more clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an index error when checking for the third neighbour:

```
                if (this[i - 1, j + 1].Gray == 1)
                {
                    if (objectArray[i - 1, j] != 0)
                    {
                        neighbors.Add(new Label(i - 1, j, 0));
                    }
                }
```

That should be 'j + 1' in all three spots.

That doesn't solve your problem, though. Your algorithm has problems when it meets diagonal edges that are black to thze nortwest and white to the southeast.

You scan the image column-wise from left to right and each column row-wise from top to bottom. You check for eight potential neighbours, but in reality, you can only add pixels to your neighbour list that you have already passed, namely the three pixels in the column to your left and the pixel above your current position. The other four adjacent pixels will have a parent (or object index) of 0.

Now consider an edge like this:

```
          #######...
          ######....
          #####.....
          ####......
          ###O......
          ###.......
          ##x.......
          #xx.......
```

('#' is black, '.' is unassigned white, 'x' is white that has been assigned a parent and 'O' marks your current position.)

You will only find black or unassigned adjacent tiles. Your neighbour list will be empty, which means that your algorithm creates a new object, although it should logically belong to the yet undiscovered object to the southeast.

(You try to back-track that by assigning all neighbour pixels the value of the new group, but that only fixes one pixel. It can also create empty groups, i.e. objects that have no corresponding pixel.)

I think that your approach is too complicated, anyway. It also doesn't account for the nooks above and to the left of the main body of components. There's no need to create extra data structures, you can do the labelling in the picture itself if you use a greyscale image. After converting the image to pure black and white, pass all pixels once. If a pixel is white, flood-fill the picture from there with a positive gray value that corresponds to the next object and increment the number of objects. Then pass all pixels again and adjust the grey value according to the object id and the number of objects.

Caveat: When I say you can do everything in the picture itself, you limit your labelling to 254 objects.

Aside: You might want to clean up your code a bit. You don't use `eqSet` and `disjointSet`, so please remove them from your code. The two arrays `objectArray` and `parents` are used alogside each other for the same thing; merge them into one. You should also refactor finding the eight neighbour pixels into a function (with one call for each potential neighbour) to make things easier to read and to avoid indexing errors as above.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will look into the flood-fill algorithm, I hadn't thought of that.